# Can't zoom in or out with mobile device

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, mobile, zooming

I made this website: `Kansvoedingsadvies.nl` with Wordpress. Now that I'm visiting the site with a mobile device (iPad and iPhone) I see that I am not able to zoom in or out. I have search on google for some anwsers but I didn't find anything there.

Is there someone who can help me?

Answer (score 5):

It's because of the following line:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0,initial-scale=1.0" />
```

It basically says the size cannot be bigger or smaller than 1. Read this for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't checked your code out in detail, it is probably related to the viewport meta tag in your HTML. Take a look here for more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html (viewport).